# difference between "Development certificate" and "Developer ID certificate"

Tags: developer-program, certificate

I am reading the pdf (from Apple) named App Distribution Guide.
In page 155 it is written that every team member can create a "Developement certificate", that the team admins can create a "Distribution certificate" (which is used to be able to update the app in iTunes Connect) but only the team agent can create "Developer ID certificate".
What actually is this?

Answer (score 1):

Page 160:
"Developer ID certificates are used to distribute your [Mac] app outside the Mac App Store."